# Probability of a random variable defined as the sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent random variables taking values $0$ and $1$ each with probability $1/2$.
Define the random variable $U$ as
$U =  X$  if $Z=0$ and $U = Y$ if $Z=1$

Let $A$ be another random variable that takes $0$ with probability $p$ and $1$ with probability $1-p$.
Define $C = U+A$.
Find the probabilities $P(C=X), P(C=Y)$ and $P(C=Z)$.

I have done the first two and have a confusion with the third. I feel it should be zero.

Comment: For example, is probability of $A$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are all zeros positive? What is value of $C$ in such case?

Comment: @mihaild C is zero in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a table of outcomes.  Note that I put $Z$ first since its outcome determines whether $U = X$ or $U = Y$.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
Z & X & Y & C = U & C = U + 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}$$
The fourth column, $C = U$, is taken with probability $p$.  The fifth column, $C = U + 1$, is taken with probability $1-p$.  Then $\Pr[C = Z]$ is $p$ times the number of rows in which $C = Z$ from the fourth column, plus $1-p$ times the number of rows in which $C = Z$ from the fifth column, divided by $8$, since each triplet $(Z, X, Y)$ has equal probability $1/8$ of occurring.  Since there are $4$ rows in the fourth column that match, and $2$ rows in the fifth column that match, the desired probability is $$\Pr[C = Z] = \frac{4p + 2(1-p)}{8} = \frac{p+1}{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to Probability theory course. Can you suggest me a book from where I can practice more questions of this kind and others?

Comment: Hi. From this table probability of P(C=X) is (7p-1)/8  but P(C=X) = P(U=X) and P(A=0) = P(Z=0) and P(A=0) = p/2.

Comment: @umm_what You made a computational error.  $$\Pr[C = X] = \frac{6p + (1-p)}{8} = \frac{5p + 1}{8}.$$  Furthermore, your reasoning is incorrect as the table shows.  If you are not convinced, choose $p = 1$ so that $A = 0$ and $C = U$.  Then $\Pr[C = X] = \Pr[U = X]$, which occurs whenever $Z = 0$ but also in the final case in the table when $X = Y = 1$, in which case $Z = 1$ makes no difference.  Thus there are $5$ outcomes in which $U = X$, not $4$.

Comment: You can also choose $p = 0$ so that $A = 1$; then according to your formula, $\Pr[C = X] = p/2 = 0$.  But again, the table shows that there is one case where $C = X$, corresponding to $(Z, X, Y, U, A, C) = (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)$.  This is because $U = Y = 0$ but then adding $A = 1$ makes $C = X = 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, Okay. Thank you !

Comment: Also can you suggest me some books to start with?

Comment: @umm_what I'm sorry, I cannot make any recommendations for textbooks as I am not familiar with the available literature.